# Worker spark webUI is not working in Apache Spark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-mllib

I have installed spark in 3 ubuntu VM's, 1 is control node and 2 data node. After starting all nodes by sbin/start-master.sh and sbin/start-slaves.sh Master webUI working but while we click the worker node WebUI not loading showing error in picture`[Master webUI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/88XI6.png)[Worker webUI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zqpWo.png)

Answer (score 0):

Possible reasons to cause this problem:

1.First you try to start the slave nodes with spark master URL as follows.
./sbin/start-slave.sh  spark://:7077

2. If above fix does not resolve the issue, try to fix it by accessing the worker UI with actual IP as 192.168.x.x instead of 127.0.0.1
3. If above steps are not resolving the issue just follow the below instructions, http://chennaihug.org/knowledgebase/spark-master-and-slaves-multi-node-installation/